# The relationship between Model A and Model B is based on the display of information about Model B from the Model A information filter In django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model called tag in which there is a category field for the input word. Now I want to use the tag model in my product model so that only the words in the product category are displayed

I have no idea for it

this is TAG model:

```
class TAG(models.Model):
  class categorychoices(models.TextChoices):
    general = 'general', _('عمومی')
    product = 'product', _('محصول')
    post = 'post', _('مقاله')
    main = 'main', _('صفحه اصلی')
    product_list = 'product_list', _('صفحه لیست محصولات')
    product_detail = 'product_detail', _('صفحه جزییات محصول')
    gallery = 'gallery', _('گالری')
    about = 'about', _('صفحه تماس با ما')
    contact = 'contact', _('صفحه ارتباط با ما')
    blog = 'blog', _('صفحه بلاگ')

category = models.CharField(max_length=15, verbose_name='تنظیم برای', 
default=categorychoices.general,
                            choices=categorychoices.choices)
word = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='کلمه کلیدی', default=' ')
```

and this is Product model :

```
 class Product(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="نام محصول")
   category = models.ForeignKey(ProductCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="دسته بندی")
   image = models.ImageField(upload_to="products", verbose_name=" تصویر محصول")
   video_aparat = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='لینک ویدیو در آپارات', 
   default='link',help_text='لینک را از قسمت اشتراک گذاری و قسمت embed کپی کنید کلمه embed باید 
   داخل لینک باشد')
   video_youtube = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='لینک ویدیو در یوتیوب', 
default='link',help_text='لینک را از قسمت اشتراک گذاری و قسمت embed کپی کنید کلمه embed باید 
داخل لینک باشد')
tag = models.ManyToManyField(TAG, verbose_name='کلمه کلیدی')

active = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="فعال / غیر فعال")
object = ProductManager()
```

ProductManager():

```
   class ProductManager(models.Manager):
       def get_active_product(self):
           return self.get_queryset().filter(active=True)

       def get_product_category(self, category):
           return self.get_queryset().filter(category__name__iexact=category, 
            active=True)

       def get_product_by_id(self, product_id):
            qs = self.get_queryset().filter(id=product_id)

            if qs.count() == 1:
                return qs.first()
            else:
                 return None
```

and ProductCategory :

```
class ProductCategory(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=15, verbose_name="نام مرجع", default="category")
titleInEn = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name="نام دسته بندی به انگلیسی")
titleInAr = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name="نام دسته بندی به عربی")
titleInFa = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name="نام دسته بندی به فارسی")
image = models.ImageField(upload_to="category", verbose_name="تصویر دسته بندی")
bannerimage = models.ImageField(upload_to="banners", verbose_name="تصویر لیست محصولات",
                                default='/site_static/images/default.jpg')

active = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="فعال / غیر فعال")

def get_category_url(self):
    return f"/products/{self.name}"

class Meta:
    verbose_name = "دسته بندی محصولات"
    verbose_name_plural = "دسته بندی محصولات"

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to display a choice field in a product form with all the tags as options?

Comment: yes I mean but multiple select tags for a product and shows all tags that their category is products

Comment: can you provide the code for `ProductManager`

Comment: also include ProductCategory too please

Comment: @Danoram I did it

Comment: Awesome! You might want to answer your question with what you did so that anyone else who has the same issue can find out how to do it.